# Openshift deployment pipeline triggered by Jenkins polling Github?

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, openshift

Most of the documentation around triggering an Openshift deployment pipeline build points towards setting up a Github webhook which targets your Openshift cluster.

Unfortunately in my case, our cluster is on an internal network and not visible to Github so of course the webook fails.

Whilst I could configure a reverse proxy to expose the Openshift cluster, I'd prefer it if instead I could get the Jenkins pod in Openshift to poll Github periodically for changes and kick off the deployment pipeline when it sees a change has been made. This is usually how our Jenkins builds work outside of Openshift. However, for some reason I can't seem to get the same thing working in Openshift Jenkins.

I'm guessing the first thing I'd need is the jenkins-persistent pod and not the Jenkins-ephemeral pod, in order to ensure that the pod is always running? I was hoping that it would be as simple as adding a "poll-github" trigger in my build yaml, but that doesn't seem to exist. Does anyone know if polling Jenkins is possible from an Openshift Jenkins pod? Thanks

Comment: Another option is to consider using a webhook proxy service such as http://www.ultrahook.com/ This means you can use webhooks with an OpenShift cluster which is behind a firewall.

Comment: Besides that, could bundle an application in an image which does the polling and run it as a ``CronJob`` in OpenShift. It could poll GitHub to get latest commit somehow, use the OpenShift REST API to query build to see what was last used, and if changes then triggers the webhook callback URL. How you would integrate that in with Jenkins pipeline I am not sure.

Comment: jenkins-persistent and jenkins-ephemeral should both remain running long term. The difference is ephemeral writes all of it's data to a tmp volume (data loss on restart), while persistent uses a persistent disk to maintain it's state throughout reboots. Either one should be able to poll externally.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: your webhook proxy solution is the most workable thing for me right now - thank you! Whilst it still doesn't answer how to get OShift Jenkins to poll GitHub, it _does_ allow me to finish what I'm doing!

Comment: @ʀɣαɳĵ : I suspected as such, given that I can always see my Jenkins pod visible. Thanks for confirming that for me.